# Power wasted and power delivered?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

If a power source is supplying a current I and a voltage V, that travels to its destination through resistors of restance R is the power delivered at the destination = $VI - RI^2$, where $(Pi=) VI$ is the power input of the power source (i.e. the total power supplied) and $RI^2$  is the  power wasted over the restance which also equals $Pi^2R/V^2$  is this correct??

Comment: The question is phrased as if there is only one voltage, but there will be a voltage drop across each resistor.

Comment: I am thinking about power transmission thru the national grid, i think in the above (i may be wrong) that the voltage in the formulas given is just the source voltage??

Comment: In the equation V=IR, "V" is the voltage drop across the resistor.

Comment: The power wasted being $RI^2$ is correct. And your equation for power delivered is correct. I'm not sure about your final expression for power wasted, how do you get that?